# Python: recursive glob in s3

Tags: python, recursion, amazon-s3, boto3, glob

I am trying to get a list of parquet files paths from s3 that are inside of subdirectories and subdirectories of subdirectories (and so on and so forth).

If it was my local file system I would do this:

```
import glob 

glob.glob('C:/Users/user/info/**/*.parquet', recursive=True)
```

I have tried using the `glob` method of [`s3fs`](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) however it doesn't have a recursive kwarg.

Is there a function I can use or do I need to implement it myself ?

Comment: doesn't ** do what you want without specifying recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 doesn't actually have subdirectories, per se.

[`boto3`'s `S3.Client.list_objects()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) supports a `prefix` argument, which should get you all the objects in a given "directory" in a bucket no matter how "deep" they appear to be.

Comment: I see, it's a shame it doesn't have a `suffix` argument. oh well i will filter it myself. thanks!

Comment: awswrangler's `s3.list_objects()` supports a `suffix` argument.

Answer (score 13):

You can use s3fs with glob:

```
import s3fs

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

s3.glob('your/s3/path/here/*.parquet')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `s3fs` is a good option until you need recursive  search as I indicated in my question

Answer (score 6):

I also wanted to download the latest file from s3 bucket but located in a specific folder. Initially, I tried using glob but couldn't find a solution to this problem. Finally, I build following function to solve this problem. You can modify this function to work with subfolders.

This function will return dictionary of all filenames and timestamp in key-value pair

(Key: file_name, value: timestamp).

Just pass bucket name and prefix (which is folder name).

```
import boto3

def get_file_names(bucket_name,prefix):
    """
    Return the latest file name in an S3 bucket folder.

    :param bucket: Name of the S3 bucket.
    :param prefix: Only fetch keys that start with this prefix (folder  name).
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    objs = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']
    shortlisted_files = dict()            
    for obj in objs:
        key = obj['Key']
        timestamp = obj['LastModified']
        # if key starts with folder name retrieve that key
        if key.startswith(prefix):              
            # Adding a new key value pair
            shortlisted_files.update( {key : timestamp} )   
    return shortlisted_files

latest_filename = get_latest_file_name(bucket_name='use_your_bucket_name',prefix = 'folder_name/')
```

Comment: please try using above function with prefix parameter set to your folder name.