# Read files from s3 bucket that match a pattern in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am reading a file from s3 in pandas.

```
aws_credentials = { 
                    "key": "xxxx", 
                    "secret": "xxxx" 
                  }

# Read data from S3 
df_aln = pd.read_csv("s3://dir/ABC/fname_0521.csv", storage_options=aws_credentials, encoding='latin-1')
```

However, I have several files with same shape and similar naming convention `fname_mmyy`. How do I read all the files that match the naming pattern and combine them into one pandas DataFrame?

I'd prefer to not write `pd.read_csv` to read each file separately.

Comment: Not sure this works with S3, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Comment: You have to iterate over all files and read them.

Answer (score 2):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69568591/687896 , you can use glob on S3. Your pattern would be something like `fname_*.csv`:

```py
# get the list of CSV files (from cited answer):
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
csvs = s3.glob('your/s3/path/to/fname*.csv')

# read them into pandas + concat the dfs
dfs = []
for csv in csvs:
    df = pandas.read_csv(csv)
    dfs.append(df)

df = pandas.concat(dfs)
```

That (or something along those lines) should work.